# Безопасность решений вопроса дополнения до целого блока и проверки на правильность ключа в реализации AES 128 ECB

Tags: безопасность, криптография, aes

Решился реализовать **AES 128 ECB** (ЯП не важен). Реализовал функцию шифрования блока, все работает, с примерами из Интернета совпадает, все отлично. После этого реализовал функцию шифрования целого файла и опять же, все работает, файлы совпадают, отлично. Но вот в процессе реализации функции шифрования целого файла я использовал решения некоторых проблем из своей головы и хотелось бы услышать мнение об безопасности этих решений и, при необходимости, более надежное решение.

**Решение номер 1.** Размер файла в байтах не всегда может быть кратен **16**, так что на целые блоки его зачастую поделить нельзя. Я решил дополнить последний блок перед шифрованием так, чтобы первыми байтами шли сами данные, далее шло **a** псевдослучайных чисел (сгенерированных при помощи вихря **Мерсенна**), а в последнем байте лежало само число **a**. Так как в подобной схеме нельзя отличить дополненный блок от не дополненного, в случае, если размер данных в байтах кратен **16**, то создается новый блок из **15** псевдослучайного мусора и числа **15** в последнем байте. При дешифровании последний блок дешифруется, в нем читается последний байт, после чего удаляют **a+1** байтов с конца этого блока.

**Решение номер 2.** Если кто-то попытается расшифровать файл с неверным ключом, то этого нельзя ни в коем случае допускать, так как файл будет обратимо, но все-таки поврежден. Следовательно, нужно придумать какой-то механизм, по которому при дешифровании можно будет определять правильный ли указан ключ. Я решил в первый блок написать **6** псевдослучайных чисел (сгенерированных при помощи того же вихря **Мерсенна**), а в последние **2** байта этого блока положить **2** уникальных числа (в моем случае - **0x20** и **0x17**), причем блок будет зашифрован.  Данные же пользователя будут начинаться со второго блока. При дешифровании первый блок будет расшифровываться, будет происходить сравнение магических чисел и последними двумя байтами первого блока, и, если, они не совпадают, то выдавать ошибку.

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Ваше **Решение 1** в случае ECB лучше, чем стандартная схема выравнивания PKCS#7 (см. ниже), так как генерирует разные концевые блоки. Но ECB в реальной жизни никто не использует, а используют либо сцепление блоков, либо режим счётчика, которые гарантируют, что одинаковые блоки в разных файлах будут порождать разный шифртекст. Поэтому для реальной жизни можно использовать детерминированное выравнивание. Например, оставить ваш вариант с длиной дополнения в последнем байте, а все остальные байты сделать нулевыми.

Про **Решение 2**. Вы собираетесь проверять правильность расшифрования по двум байтам. Это даёт вероятность ошибки `1/65536`. По меркам современной криптографии это неприемлемо высокая вероятность. NIST рекомендует использовать от 96 до 256 бит. Но уже 128 бит равно размеру блока, что в случае ECB и константной метки будет означать, что любой из зашифрованных файлов будет начинаться с одного и того же шифртекста. Это открывает дорогу для атаки на открытый текст. То есть супостат, зная константную метку, может подбирать ключ, просто  перебирая ключи, шифруя известную константную метку и сравнивая результат с шифртекстом.

Поэтому я бы рекомендовал вам воспользоваться уже проверенными рецептами.

1. **Выравнивание**. Для совместимости с другими программами шифрования и дешифрования вам стоит реализовать [схему дополнения PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315.html#section-10.3)

   ```
    2.   Some content-encryption algorithms assume the
         input length is a multiple of k octets, where k > 1, and
         let the application define a method for handling inputs
         whose lengths are not a multiple of k octets. For such
         algorithms, the method shall be to pad the input at the
         trailing end with k - (l mod k) octets all having value k -
         (l mod k), where l is the length of the input. In other
         words, the input is padded at the trailing end with one of
         the following strings:

                  01 -- if l mod k = k-1
                 02 02 -- if l mod k = k-2
                             .
                             .
                             .
               k k ... k k -- if l mod k = 0

         The padding can be removed unambiguously since all input is
         padded and no padding string is a suffix of another. This
         padding method is well-defined if and only if k < 256;
         methods for larger k are an open issue for further study.
   ```
2. **Режим шифрования** ECB в реальной жизни никто не использует. Основная проблема безопасности ECB в том, что одинаковые блоки в разных файлах шифруются одинаково. Поэтому если атакующие знают структуру данных, они могут извлечь какую-то информацию даже не зная ключ.

Поэтому вам не стоит останавливаться на изучении одноблочного шифрования. Как минимум, освойте метод сцепления блоков [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)) и режим счётчика [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR)).

3. Для проверки правильности расшифрования можно вычислить контрольную сумму или хэш открытого теста, добавить вычисленную контрольную сумму к выравненным открытым данным и зашифровать это значение вместе с открытым текстом. При расшифровании параллельно считать контрольную сумму расшифрованных данных и сравнить получившееся значение с контрольной суммой из последнего блока. Если вычисленная контрольная сумма совпала с расшифрованной контрольной суммой, значит (а) ключ верен и (б) шифротекст не был изменён.

Вообще это называется [Authenticated Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption), и придумано множество схем.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию о уязвимости ECB, попробую понять и реализовать CBC. Но все-таки вопрос про мои два "решения" остается открытым. Повлияют ли и сильно на криптостойкость шифрования мои "решения"?

Comment: @gth-other добавил в ответ про ваши решения. Также добавил ссылку на режим счётчика (CTR)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте для шифрования Win32API [BCryptEncrypt()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptencrypt) из Bcypt.dll. Если этой функции в последнем параметре передать флаг **BCRYPT_BLOCK_PADDING**, то она сама делает входящие данные кратными 16-байт. И алгоритм шифрования выберите нормальный, например (как было сказано выше) "Cipher Block Chaining", CBC. Он шифрует следующий блок результатом предыдущего, что в разы увеличивает крипто-стойкость. Вот их схемы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь видно, что если в режиме ECB подать на вход цепочку из 32 нулей, то оба 16-байтных блока будут зашифрованы одинаково - это уязвимость, поэтому логичней использовать CBC, или любой другой режим, типа CTR,CFB,CCM,GCM. Функция `BCryptEncrypt()` может шифровать во-всех режимах.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию про уязвимость, но Win32API использовать не буду. Если бы мне нужен был просто функционал без точного понимания принципа работы, то я бы просто взял какой-нибудь OpenSSL, вместо использования некросплатформенного API, которого даже нет на моей системе (: